# MalformedJsonException on Retrofit and Gson

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to make a retrofit call and i'm getting MalformedJsonException.

This is my call:

```
String idFoto = "1ead0a1f-bbc4-46bd-901c-7988c0e6c68b";
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl(Global.URL_BASE)
     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
     .build();
FotosAPI service = retrofit.create(FotosAPI.class);
Call<String> obtenerFotoCall = service.getFoto(Global.getToken(), idFoto);
```

This is my interface:

```
public interface FotosAPI {
     @GET(Global.URL_FOTO + "{id}")
     Call<String> getFoto(@Header("Authorization") String token, @Path("id") String id);
}
```

The call enqueue enters onFailure method, and the error is "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 2 path $".

I made the changes to set lenient like this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
     .baseUrl(Global.URL_BASE)
     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
     .build();
```

Then, I have a different error: "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 1 path $"

I think that the error maybe is in the conversion of Gson of the idFoto string value, but I don't know what is wrong.

Can someone help me please?

Thank you guys!

Comment: You should required `ToStringConverterFactory` because I think your response is in `String` so no need to convert in `GsonConverterFactory`

Comment: can you see what the raw json response looks like?

Comment: The raw call looks like that: Request{method=GET, url=http://10.0.2.2:8080/DGCWS/rest/photo/1ead0a1f-bbc4-46bd-901c-7988c0e6c68b, tag=null}. I don't know where to see the raw json response when the call result enter onFailure method

Comment: I have other post call that have a String response (to get the token) and using gson with lenient I have no problem

Answer (score 0):

Please check the JSON that you are getting from server, In my case JSON I was getting from the server was not valid.

Try to check your JSON from Postman or some other tool.

Comment: Hi Shivam. Thanks for your response. I did that and i get the correct answer (a photo in base64).

Answer (score 0):

Like M D says (thank you very much man!), the solution is to change GsonConverter for ToStringCorverterFactory.

This is the class that I use:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Converter;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class ToStringConverterFactory extends Converter.Factory {
    private static final MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = MediaType.parse("text/plain");

    @Override
    public Converter<ResponseBody, ?> responseBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] annotations, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if (String.class.equals(type)) {
            return new Converter<ResponseBody, String>() {
                @Override
                public String convert(ResponseBody value) throws IOException {
                    return value.string();
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Converter<?, RequestBody> requestBodyConverter(Type type, Annotation[] parameterAnnotations,
                                                          Annotation[] methodAnnotations, Retrofit retrofit) {

        if (String.class.equals(type)) {
            return new Converter<String, RequestBody>() {
                @Override
                public RequestBody convert(String value) throws IOException {
                    return RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, value);
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

And then you only have to change the retrofit builder to this:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(Global.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(new ToStringConverterFactory())
                        .build();
```